# Object values to map

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, mapping

I want to map specific properties from an array of objects into another array of objects while using a value as a key in the new object.

For example, I have this object (the syntax doesn't matter is just pseudo-code):

```
const obj= [
  {id:1 , height: 57 ,name:'jhon' , state: 'true', time: ''},
  {id:2 , height:64 ,name:'max' , state: 'true', time: ''},
  {id:3 , height:62 ,name:'tim' , state: 'false', time: ''},
  {id:4 , height:510 ,name:'alex' , state: 'false', time: ''},
  {id:5 , height: 510 ,name:'frank' , state: 'true', time: ''}
]
```

And I want to make a map with the name as the key and height as the value, so it looks like this:

```
[
  {jhon : 57},
  {max : 64},
  ...
]
```

Comment: you can try `reduce`

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: I have been trying different solutions that I have found on google but none succeded or the ones that did where extremly long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm setting the name as a key using "[]" and returning a object with the height

```js
const obj = [
  { id: 1, height: 57, name: 'jhon', state: 'true', time: '' },
  { id: 2, height: 64, name: 'max', state: 'true', time: '' },
  { id: 3, height: 62, name: 'tim', state: 'false', time: '' },
  { id: 4, height: 510, name: 'alex', state: 'false', time: '' },
  { id: 5, height: 510, name: 'frank', state: 'true', time: '' }
]

const result = obj.map(user => {
  return {[user.name]: user.height}
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [parameter destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names).

```
obj.map(({ name, height }) => ({ [name]: height }))
```

```js
const obj = [
  { id: 1, height: 57, name: 'jhon', state: 'true', time: '' },
  { id: 2, height: 64, name: 'max', state: 'true', time: '' },
  { id: 3, height: 62, name: 'tim', state: 'false', time: '' },
  { id: 4, height: 510, name: 'alex', state: 'false', time: '' },
  { id: 5, height: 510, name: 'frank', state: 'true', time: '' }
]

console.log(obj.map(({ name, height }) => ({ [name]: height })))
```

Answer (score 1):

> you can also use reduce

```js
const obj= [
    {id:1 , height: 57 ,name:'jhon' , state: 'true', time: ''},
    {id:2 , height:64 ,name:'max' , state: 'true', time: ''},
    {id:3 , height:62 ,name:'tim' , state: 'false', time: ''},
    {id:4 , height:510 ,name:'alex' , state: 'false', time: ''},
    {id:5 , height: 510 ,name:'frank' , state: 'true', time: ''},
    ]

    const newObj = obj.reduce((accu,curr)=>{
        const ob = {
            [curr.name]:curr.height
        }
        accu.push(ob)
        return accu
    },[])

    console.log(newObj)
```

```
console.log(newObj)
```